# Multiple attributes for configurable product?

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, custom, sku

I am trying to set up a configurable product using two separate custom attributes and can’t see how I can get it working.

Basically this product has two separate options- size and color. There are two size options- 10 and 20. And there are about eight different color options. The customer selects the size and then a color.

However the price needs to be different depending on what size the customer picks, and also the individual simple product SKUs for the colors will be different as well. So if they pick size 10, they get a certain list of all the colors in the next dropdown, but if they select size 20 then they will get a different list of colors with different SKUs.

I can’t see any way of getting this set up so the price depends on the size attribute and the color list changes depending on which size is picked in the previous dropdown.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you described here is the exact functionality of the magento configurable products.
Take a look at this for more details: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product.
When you create a configurable product you will also have the option to add a price delta to the options you use.
So for example for the size: 
Size 10 can have a +3E.
The down side is that all the size 10 will have that extra charge.
Then you can set for color green a price difference of -2.
This means that when selecting size 10 and color green you will have the price: BASE+3-2 = BASE + 1.

As for the colors depending on the size, this is what Magento does.
If you create a configurable product and you create simple products for only a few variations of colors and sizes only those will be visible in the product view page

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see anywhere where I can add this "delta"? I want all size-10 products to have the same price (regardless of color) and size-20 products will have a different price. Where do I set this?

Comment: When creating a configurable product you will see a tab called 'Associated products'. From there you can select the simple products that are associated to the configurable one. In the section 'Super product attributes configuration' after cliking on a simple product you should see a box called 'price' for each size and color of the products you select.

Comment: Ok, but how can I make it work so that if I select say size 20 in the first dropdown in the front end, I then get a different set of colors loaded in the 2nd dropdown? The colors will have different SKUs depending on whether I select size 10 or size 20.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas as to how I can do this?

Comment: The dropdowns are automatically populated on the frontend by the associated/simple products you created in the backend. So if you create a product with size 20 in red, green, and blue, and another product in size 10 in black, the frontend will let you select only the colors that are in that size.